# Device Info JSON Deserializing

Tags: c#, json

I've read a number of questions about this subject on here but never understood how to sort the problem.

When setting up the classes from JSON output with JSON2CSharp i get the following output as I have number values for each name with the public class __invalid_type__1 and __invalid_type__2, how do i over come this? I've looked at using Dictionary but don't understand fully how to implement this as I'm new to coding and c#, or is there a better way to do this?

```
[DataContract]
public class State
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool on { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int bri { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class __invalid_type__1
{
    [DataMember]
    public State state { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
}

[DataContract]
public class State2
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool on { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int bri { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class __invalid_type__2
{
    [DataMember]
    public State2 state { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public __invalid_type__1 __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public __invalid_type__2 __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
}
```

my code for deserialzing Json is

```
 public async static Task<RootObject> GetL ()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format("http://192.168.0.71/api/apikey/");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
     }
```

Original String

```
{
    "1": {
        "state": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 254,
            "alert": "select",
            "reachable": true
        },
        "type": "Dimmable    light",
        "name": "Table Light",
        "modelid": "LWB010",
        "manufacturername": "Philips",
        "uniqueid": "00:17:88:01:02:49:cf:db-0b",
        "swversion": "1.15.2_r19181",
        "swconfigid": "60083D2F",
        "productid": "Philips-LWB010-1-A19DLv3"
    },
    "2": {
        "state": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 1,
            "alert": "select",
            "reachable": true
        },
        "type": "Dimmable light",
        "name": "Dressing Room",
        "modelid": "LWB010",
        "manufacturername": "Philips",
        "uniqueid": "00:17:88:01:02:44:60:94-0b",
        "swversion": "1.15.2_r19181",
        "swconfigid": "60083D2F",
        "productid": "Philips-LWB010-1-A19DLv3"
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the JSON-string look like?

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Comment: Rename `__invalid_type__2` to something sensible, like `DeviceInfo` and deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, DeviceInfo>`.